# .htaccess - redirected you too many times

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, server, dns

htaccess gurus, I am having issues with connectivity with one of our websites that was working fine until last Friday (27th jan), [www.astroflame.com](http://www.astroflame.com). We currently use easyspace.com for domain name, hosting, emails etc. I have contacted the provider but they say everything is fine but when I do random tests on Edge, Chrome, Firefox (including private modes). Sometimes the site loads ok and sometimes this redirected you too many times error appears

[www.astroflame.com](http://www.astroflame.com) redirected you too many times
to fix this issue, try clearing your cookies
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Now the web service provider said to update our htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But I am still seeing this redirected you too many times error. The site it self is just basic HTML, CSS, and a bit js.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Did you clear your browser caches?

Comment: yes i have cleared cache, but still seeing the error?

Comment: What was your htaccess before? What else do you have in your htaccess file? What is the nature of the redirect loop? What are the tests you are doing? If you are only "sometimes" getting a loop for the same request then it probably isn't htaccess. The proposed htaccess code the web service provided assumes you are behind a proxy that manages SSL, is that the case?

Comment: my htaccess file that was used before, but this doesnt seem to work as well: RewriteEngine On

### START WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS

Comment: Not sure what the nature of the redirect loop is, with the current htaccess file that i am using seen at the top (of this question) in the firefox browser when i type in "www.astroflame.com" I get this error : The page isn’t redirecting properly. An error occurred during a connection to www.astroflame.com. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. which just stays on this page. now in Edge similar error message but after 3 seconds it loads the site

Comment: Im know getting the same error message in firefox and edge all the time (when start a browser with a cleared cache or when i open and close these browsers), we have the SSL certificate through the web service, in this case easyspace. So im not sure if its something to do with the SSL certificate? when i test the this SSL on https://www.whynopadlock.com/ it sometimes says there is an SSL and sometimes it comes back with an error "The SSL certificate tests failed. Please be sure that you can connect to your site over SSL and try again."

Comment: Can anyone else see this redirect error from firefox or edge?